# Generate negative predictive value using cross_val_score in sklearn for model performance evaluation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, metrics

As part of evaluating a model's metrics, I would like to use cross_val_score in sklearn to generate negative predictive value for a binary classification model.

In example below, I set the 'scoring' parameter within cross_val_score to calculate and print 'precision' (mean and standard deviations from 10-fold cross-validation) for positive predictive value of the model:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
log=LogisticRegression()    
log_prec = cross_val_score(log, x, y, cv=10, scoring='precision')
print("PPV(mean, std): ", np.round(log_prec.mean(), 2), np.round(log_prec.std(), 2))
```

How can I use something like the above line of code to generate negative predictive value/NPV (likelihood of a predicted negative to be a true negative) from within the cross_val_score method?

sklearn provides many scoring options (eg: roc_auc, recall, accuracy, F1, etc) but unforunately not one for NPV...

Comment: Do you have a binary classification problem? If so, why don't you invert the label definition? Then the PPV will correspond to the NPV in you original problem.

Comment: This is a clever work-around and helpful indeed! Please post this as your answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`make_scorer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) to pass in `pos_label=0` to the precision score function ([`metrics.precision_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_score)) to get NPV. Like this:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, precision_score
npv = cross_val_score(log, x, y, cv=10, scoring=make_scorer(precision_score, pos_label=0))
```

For more details see this [sklearn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions).

Answer (score 4):

For a binary classification problem you can invert the label definition. Then the PPV will correspond to the NPV in you original problem